# UIScrollView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, scrollview

I am working in iPhone application, Using UIScrollView to set in Horizontal, add 5 images in UIScrollView,and its working fine. 
(I want to show 2nd image in opening time) Then i tried, when the screen shows, at the time 2nd image show. But i tried my level best, but i did not do that, please any one help me

Thanks in advance

I tried this:

```
 UIScrollView *scroll1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 360)];
    scroll1.contentSize=CGSizeMake(2700, 360);
    [scroll1 setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    scroll1.pagingEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scroll1];

    UIImageView *SlideImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
    SlideImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage];

    UIImageView *SlideImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];
    SlideImage1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage1];

    UIImageView *SlideImage2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(600,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"];
    SlideImage2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage2];

    UIImageView *SlideImage3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(900,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage3.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"];
    SlideImage3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage3];

    UIImageView *SlideImage4 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1200,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage4.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"];
    SlideImage4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage4];

    UIImageView *SlideImage5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1500,0, 300, 360)];
    SlideImage5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img6.png"];
    SlideImage5.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll1 addSubview:SlideImage5];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[scroll1 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(300, 0) animated:FALSE];
```

Comment: you add your vote up for your answer, vote down for  others answer

Comment: you make dummy votes to increase your reputation in this account